# Beautiful Soup extracting text from a H2 field

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to understand how I can fix some Beautiful Soup extraction,

below is the example code I was using but now its coming back with

```
---> 66             dista = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'RaceHeader_title_1Yk'}).text
     67             dista = dista.split( " " )[-1]
     68             horses = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'Entries_entry_2Xt'})

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text
```

Below is the code I was using and a example of what it is scraping , Ideally I am trying to get the "1600" as the output

```
 dista = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'RaceHeader_title_1Yk'}).text
 dista = dista.split( " " )[-1]


<h2 class="RaceHeader_title_1Yk">
<span class="RaceHeader_titleNumber_uNI">R1</span>
"MT SOMERS HONEY MAIDEN 1600"
"1600"
</h2>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: What's the url you're scraping?

Comment: https://new.tab.co.nz/extended-form/2020-09-18-m6-r1

Comment: Thanks , ill try and figure out how to incorporate it into my current code and reply back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# URL to be scrapped
link = "https://new.tab.co.nz/extended-form/2020-09-18-m6-r1"

# Sending a get request to get the content of page
source = requests.get(link).text

# Parsing with help of bs4
soup = bs(source,"html.parser")

# Extracting the specific element from bs4 object
content = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'RaceHeader_title_1Yk'})

# Getting the desired content
result = content.text.split(" ")[-1]

print(result)
```

Output

```
1600
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://new.tab.co.nz/extended-form/2020-09-18-m6-r1").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("h2", {"class": "RaceHeader_title_1Yk"}).text.split()[-1])
```

Output `1600`

To get all horses add this line:

```
print([h.text for h in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "EntryHeader_runner_UwW"})])
```

Output:

```
['Danny Green (8) 5 g bay', 'Eisenhower (10) 5 g bay', 'On The Rivet (13) 4 g bay', 'Point Break (11) 4 g brown', 'Magie Noire (7) 4 g bay', 'Mazzoni (12) 7 g bay', 'Miss Oaks (3) 5 m bay', 'Turn Your Eyes (6) 5 m chestnut', 'Repulse (5) 4 m bay', 'Spindleshanks (9) 5 m bay', 'Nifty (1) 6 m chestnut', 'Tennessee Rock (14) 4 m bay', 'Wendy Darling (4) 4 m brown', "Tappy's Lad (2) 3 g brown"]
```